# Regex of consecutive punctuation in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a character vector that looks like this:

```
z <- c("./.", "To/TO", "my/PRP$", "starved/VBN", ",/,", "wretched/JJ") # test input

 [9992] "./."                           
 [9993] "To/TO"                         
 [9994] "my/PRP$"                       
 [9995] "starved/VBN"                   
 [9996] ",/,"
 [9997] "wretched/JJ"
```

I want to remove all entries that consist of three consecutive punctuation marks, resulting in something like this:

```
 [9993] "To/TO"                         
 [9994] "my/PRP$"                       
 [9995] "starved/VBN"                   
 [9997] "wretched/JJ"
```

I've tried different regex expressions:

```
sub("[:punct:]/[:punct:]", "", z)
```

and

```
sub("[:punct:]{3}", "", z)
```

with either single/double brackets, both yield:

```
 [9992] "./."                        
 [9993] "To"                         
 [9994] "my$"                        
 [9995] "starved"                    
 [9996] ",/,"                        
 [9997] "wretched"
```

Any ideas?  And I apologize in advance if the question is dumb; I'm not very good at this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- c("./.", "To/TO", "my/PRP$", "starved/VBN", ",/,", "wretched/JJ") # test input

grep("[[:punct:]]{3}", x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
## [1] "To/TO"       "my/PRP$"     "starved/VBN" "wretched/JJ"
```